# How to parametrize my exports?

Tags: mef

I'd like to be able to parametrize my exports not only with types (as in, *generic exports*), but also with values.

Something like:

```
    class Greeter
    {
        readonly string _format;
        public Greeter( string format ) { _format = format; }

        public string Greet( string name ) { return string.Format( _format, name ); }
    }

    // ...

    var e = new ExportProvider();
    e.ExportParametrized<Greeter>( args: new[] { "Hi, {0}!" } );
    e.ExportParametrized<Greeter>( args: new[] { "¡Hola, {0}!" } );

    // And then:
    [ImportMany] IEnumerable<Greeter> Greeters { get; set; }

    foreach( var g in Greeters ) Console.WriteLine( g.Greet( "John" ) );

    // Should print out:
    //   Hello, John!
    //   ¡Hola, John!
```

One might ask: why don't I simply export the value `new Greeter( "Hello, {0}!" )` using `ComposablePartExportProvider` and `CompositionBatch`?
While this approach would work in this particular case, it has an important flaw: if the `Greeter` class had any imports of its own, they would not be satisfied.

The usual way I would go about this is to declare two classes - `EnglishGreeter` and `SpanishGreeter`, inherit them both from `Greeter`, and then provide the appropriate arguments in the call to base constructor.

But this doesn't work for two reasons:

1. This is a lot of noise to write. Not only do I have to type the whole shebang, I also have to come up with **names** for those classes, and it doesn't always make sense to have names. Not to mention the DRY principle. But even besides the noise...
2. Sometimes I don't know the parameters upfront. Say, for example, my greeting formats were coming from some kind of config file.

**Here is another thought**, to somewhat clarify what I'm looking for.
This problem is *almost* solved in the `TypeCatalog`. See, the `TypeCatalog` knows about the type and it calls the type's constructor to create the part on demand.
One can think of this process from another standpoint: the catalog has a factory function; using that function, it creates the part, then satisfies its non-prerequisite imports, and then returns the part back to the requestor.
Now, in the particular case of `TypeCatalog`, the factory function just happens to be the type's own constructor. If only I could hook in and replace the factory function with my own, but still leverage the rest of the machinery, that would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using property exports. You could define a class specifically for those kinds of exports, and it will look like this:

```
class MyParameterizedExports
{
    [Export(typeof(Greeter))]
    private Greeter EnglishGreeter
    {
        get
        {
            Greeter g = new Greeter("Hi, {0}!");
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(g);
            return g;
        }
    }

    [Export(typeof(Greeter))]
    private Greeter SpanishGreeter
    {
        get
        {
            Greeter g = new Greeter("¡Hola, {0}!");
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(g);
            return g;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you export two separate `Greeter` instances without having to define a new class for each type of `Greeter`.

Comment: Nope, I cannot. First, just like the `CompositionBatch.AddExportedValue` solution, this approach will not get `Greeter`'s own imports satisfied. Second, this still doesn't work for dynamic case. And third, this is still a lot of noise. Almost as much.

Comment: Although not perfect, this solution is still more dynamic than `AddExportedValue`, since it only creates the instance when it's imported, and not when it's exported. Furthermore, it's possible to have the getter call `SatisfyImportsOnce` on the returned instance. To make it more dynamic, you'll probably need to create your own catalog/export provider that will read this from a configuration file rather than an export.

Comment: Well, I do realize that I could just rewrite the whole machinery myself. I don't have to ask a question on SO to know that. The solution I'm looking for involves reusing existing machinery and getting rid of all the unnecessary noise.

Comment: Whoa, whoa! After your edit, this won't even compile. The `container` identifier is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I assumed this didn't need any further explanation. The container can either be imported or retrieved with `ServiceLocator`. If you prefer, I'll rollback my answer.

Comment: Yes, I do realize it can be overcome with enough extra code, but that's the whole point! I don't want to write extra code! Look at it: now I have to declare a class, import `ICompositionService` (and not forget to export it when creating the container!), declare a prop for each export, and in its getter, call `SatisfyInportsOnce`, which creates a need for an extra local variable (and BTW: if you were going to propose making an extension method to shorten this, save your breath - I already have it). With that much code, I might as well just use inherited classes.

Comment: ...And all for what? It doesn't even solve the original problem! "Parametrizing" means "using parameters". A constant is, by definition, not a parameter.